# open() в python просит integer

Tags: python, type-error

Пытаюсь открыть файл в питоне через with open()

```
def annot_search(i1):
    path = r'C:\Users\5286\Desktop\Study\KiTG Alt\cit-HepTh-unsorted\\' + str(i1) + '.abs'
    # Читаем в строку всё содержимое файла
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        s = str(f.read())
    # Ищем индекс второго и третьего вхождений подстроки "\n\\\\\n" (всего их 3 - нас интересует текст между 2 и 3)
    i2 = s.index(r'\n\\\\\n', s.index(r'\n\\\\\n')+8, -1)
    i3 = s.index(r'\n\\\\\n', i2+8, -1)
    # annot - текст между этими \\
    annot = s[i2+10:i3:]
    return annot
```

Делаю в collab и pycharm. Коллаб в принципе отказался работать, выдавая ошибку

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-1b7c9bdac3e3> in <module>
      3 print(path)
      4 # Читаем в строку всё содержимое файла
----> 5 with open(path, 'rb') as f:
      6   s = str(f.read())
      7 # Ищем индекс второго и третьего вхождений подстроки "\n\\\\\n" (всего их 3 - нас интересует текст между 2 и 3)

TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Путь к файлу в коллабе заменён на нужный (файл подтягивается из хранилища коллаба, не с компьютера).
До какого-то момента всё работало в pycharm, однако после некоторых изменений других частей кода и он начал выдавать такую же ошибку

Так вот вопрос: зачем open'у нужен integer? Куда его пихать? До этого прекрасно работал с путём+режимом

С os.path.join() также ничего не меняется

Comment: У вас где-то в коде была переопределена функция open. Нужно найти у вас в коде `def open(`, и переименовать, чтобы имя не совпадало с именем стандартной функции.

Comment: @insolor похоже на `from os import *` — в Python 3.8 функция `os.open` выдаёт в точности такой текст ошибки

Comment: @andreymal, возможно и такое. Ну тогда можно посоветовать только никогда не использовать импорты звездочкой.

Comment: Да, проблема была как раз в импорте звёздочкой. Всё решил, всем спасибо за советы!

Answer (score 0):

Итак, я разобрался, в чем дело
В коде был импорт os как:

```
from os import *
```

Что было опрометчивым решением, ибо open() есть как в os, так и в io (мне нужен был именно из io)
Всё решилось нормальным импортом os, io и заменой на нужный open():

```
import os
import io
...
with io.open(path, 'rb') as f:
...
```

Comment: `open` и `io.open` это одна и та же функция, поэтому импортировать `io` нет необходимости